# How to set up Google Pay for my django online ecommerce website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, google-pay

I have an online e-commerce website where the user can trade images with each other
What I'm trying to achieve is: seller requests the buyer to give him money, the buyer clicks on the "accept payment" and then set up payment with his Google Pay account, finally the seller will get charged in his Google Pay account

How can I do so? I'm using Django 3.1

Here is my Trade model

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='seller', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='buyer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is the "Accept_trade" view

```
def accept_trade(request, pk):
    trade = get_object_or_404(Trade, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'trade/accept_trade.html', {'trade': trade})
    else:
        # PAY
        payment = Payment.objects.create(
            variant='default',
            description= 'A trade',
            total=Decimal(trade.price),
            tax=Decimal(0),
            currency='USD',
            delivery=Decimal(0),
            billing_first_name=trade.buyer.first_name,
            billing_last_name=trade.buyer.last_name,
            customer_ip_address='127.0.0.1'
        )
        payment.save()
        payment.capture()
        payment.release()
        return redirect('home')
```

my accept_trade.html

```
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Accept trade | {% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
<div class="shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 col-md-5 bg-white rounded float-right m-4 p-4">
    <p>Seller: {{ trade.seller.username }}</p>
    <p style="color: #2ecc71;">Price: ${{ trade.price }}</p>
</div>
<form action="{% url 'trade:accept_trade' trade.id %}" method="post" class="m-4">
    {% csrf_token%}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="padding:10px 30px; border-radius: 200px; margin: 30px; letter-spacing: 1px; word-spacing: 4px;">Pay and get product</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://django-payments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to do this. So, for example, you could do:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

from payments import get_payment_model

Payment = get_payment_model()
payment = Payment.objects.create(
    variant='default',  # this is the variant from PAYMENT_VARIANTS
    description='Book purchase',
    total=Decimal(120),
    tax=Decimal(20),
    currency='USD',
    delivery=Decimal(10),
    billing_first_name='Sherlock',
    billing_last_name='Holmes',
    billing_address_1='221B Baker Street',
    billing_address_2='',
    billing_city='London',
    billing_postcode='NW1 6XE',
    billing_country_code='UK',
    billing_country_area='Greater London',
    customer_ip_address='127.0.0.1')

# https://django-payments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#making-a-payment
```

Comment: I was following with the documentation and at it's telling me now "Only payments with the preauth status can be captured." What should i do?

Comment: @INeedHelpPlease Check https://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Preauthorized+payment#:~:text=Any%20agreement%20between%20a%20bank,a%20certain%20amount%20every%20month.&text=For%20example%2C%20a%20customer%20may,his%20internet%20bill%20each%20month.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it works, I just have few questions, should I redirect the user to the payment_details form when making a payment? and now after the user pays how can I make the "seller" receive his money?

Comment: @INeedHelpPlease I'm not sure how your application so I can't answer that.